# What is the process to code-sign Windows kernel driver for a freelance developer on Windows 10, 64-bit?

Tags: code-signing, code-signing-certificate, windows-kernel

I'm trying to research the topic of signing my 64-bit Windows 10 kernel driver as a freelance developer, but I'm finding a lot of contradicting information.

First off, I tried following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/get-a-code-signing-certificate) Microsoft document, and I'm already on the 3rd level of depth in it ([level 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/register-for-the-hardware-program)), ([level 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles)) and it doesn't make it clearer.

I see that they want me to have an EV code signing certifice. Then register for a hardware portal, and then also create `Azure AD directory`. Is that correct? What other gotchas are out there?

---

PS. I also see that EV certificates are issued to organizations only. But how is it that the [`Process Hacker`](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker)'s driver is signed by a certificate issued to an individual?

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/kernel-mode-code-signing-policy--windows-vista-and-later-

Comment: @MikeF you won't typically be able to get an EV certificate without a company. I'd be surprised if you were able to obtain one. Last time I checked you needed to register in the "Partner Center for Windows Hardware" (however, this "place" has been renamed so many times I'd not be surprised if the name had changed meanwhile). From there you can "register" your certificate and request attestation signing from Microsoft. If you wanted to actually have your driver certified you need the [HLK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Hardware_Lab_Kit) and pass the test for your driver category.

Comment: As for the 2016 signature, rules differed at the time. But whether "Windows" complains also depends a lot on how you load/install the driver. Talking to the SCM directly - at least in the past - was a way to circumvent all those pesky warnings you got with the (at that time official) installation methods (e.g. [DIFx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/difx-guidelines)). EV is only an attribute and signifies that the CA did additional checking (and usually that there is some insurance and whatever ...).